# Timezone in Telegraf or InfluxDB?

Tags: tracking, influxdb, grafana, statsd

I am using Telegraf as a server to collect StatsD data from Python and send it to InfluxDB. However, the data I am getting on InfluxDB has a different timezone than mine. Where do I have to configure the timezone settings: Telegraf or InfluxDB?

Note: I will use this data with Grafana, in case I have to set something up there too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Telegraf` and `influxdb` are both using `UTC` as default timezone. As far as I know you cant set another timezone for them. What you want to do is simply use the "Local browser time" option in `grafana`.

[image]